Changing the frequency of the tuning forks
I just bought some tuning forks with frequencies of 128 Hz and 512 Hz. However, when I tested them using an app, their frequencies turned out to be lower than the specified values. How can I increase the frequency of the tuning forks? Should I bend the prongs in or out, cut the material, or add material?

Random page with some information on modifying tuning forks.  https://www.tunelab-world.com/calforks.html#:~:text=If%20the%20pitch%20of%20the,as%20to%20make%20them%20longer.

I see that mike1994 answered this question and then deleted his answer. Not sure why. He was right. "If you want to increase the frequency of vibration of a tuning fork removing some material would be the way to go." Try a grinder.
If it was too high, gluing a small mass on would help.
